# Can't deserialize data with kafka and springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to integrate my spring boot app with a remote kafka, but I encountered an error when starting my application. The error occurred once the consumer listen to the remote kafka, please refer below:

```
2020-04-02 08:28:58.795  INFO 17760 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService
2020-04-02 08:28:58.855  INFO 17760 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-02 08:28:58.858  INFO 17760 --- [  restartedMain] kafka.topic.queue.Application            : Started Application in 16.273 seconds (JVM running for 18.555)
2020-04-02 08:28:59.874  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=json] Cluster ID: l6gelyg5RtKbGqghgTYnAA
2020-04-02 08:28:59.876  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=json] Discovered group coordinator xx.xxx.5.xxx:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2020-04-02 08:28:59.884  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=json] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2020-04-02 08:28:59.886  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : json: partitions revoked: []
2020-04-02 08:28:59.887  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=json] (Re-)joining group
2020-04-02 08:29:00.805  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=json] (Re-)joining group
2020-04-02 08:29:01.617  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=json] Successfully joined group with generation 37
2020-04-02 08:29:01.635  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=json] Setting newly assigned partitions: devtopic-2, devtopic-1, devtopic-0
2020-04-02 08:29:02.026  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=json] Setting offset for partition devtopic-2 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=5, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=xx.xxx.5.xxx:9092 (id: 1 rack: null), epoch=0}}
2020-04-02 08:29:02.028  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=json] Setting offset for partition devtopic-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=7, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=xx.xxx.5.xxx:9092 (id: 1 rack: null), epoch=0}}
2020-04-02 08:29:02.028  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=json] Setting offset for partition devtopic-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=7, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=xx.xxx.5.xxx:9092 (id: 1 rack: null), epoch=0}}
2020-04-02 08:29:02.640  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : json: partitions assigned: [devtopic-2, devtopic-1, devtopic-0]
**2020-04-02 08:29:03.891  INFO 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] k.topic.queue.consumer.MessageConsumer   : Logger 1 [JSON] received key null: Type [N/A] | Payload: Name::toString() -> {id=1,fname=test,mname=test,lname=test} | Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = devtopic, partition = 1, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 7, CreateTime = 1585747622488, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 53, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = Name::toString() -> {id=1,fname=test,mname=test,lname=test})**
2020-04-02 08:29:04.300 ERROR 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: null

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition devtopic-1 at offset 8. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[108]] from topic [devtopic]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'l': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"l"; line: 1, column: 2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:722) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3556) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2651) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:856) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:753) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._initForReading(ObjectReader.java:357) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1704) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1282) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:438) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1268) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3600(Fetcher.java:124) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1492) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1600(Fetcher.java:1332) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:645) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:606) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1263) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1225) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1012) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:968) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:905) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]

2020-04-02 08:29:04.305 ERROR 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: null

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition devtopic-1 at offset 8. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[108]] from topic [devtopic]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'l': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"l"; line: 1, column: 2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:722) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3556) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2651) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:856) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:753) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._initForReading(ObjectReader.java:357) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1704) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1282) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:438) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1268) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3600(Fetcher.java:124) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1492) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1600(Fetcher.java:1332) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:645) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:606) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1263) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1225) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1012) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:968) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:905) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]

2020-04-02 08:29:04.308 ERROR 17760 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: null

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition devtopic-1 at offset 8. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[108]] from topic [devtopic]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'l': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"l"; line: 1, column: 2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:722) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3556) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2651) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:856) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:753) ~[jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._initForReading(ObjectReader.java:357) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1704) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1282) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:438) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1268) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3600(Fetcher.java:124) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1492) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1600(Fetcher.java:1332) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:645) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:606) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1263) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1225) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1012) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:968) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:905) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
```

the error goes on until I stop the application from running. Also, you may notice that before the error occurred I was able to consume a message from the topic..

I will provide my configurations below:

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: xx.xxx.5.xxx:9092
    consumer:
      #bootstrap-servers: xx.xxx.5.xxx:9092
      group-id: json
      auto-offset-reset: latest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: kafka.topic.queue.entity
            use:
              type:
                headers: false
            value:
              default:
                type: kafka.topic.queue.entity.Name
    producer:
      #bootstrap-servers: xx.xxx.5.xxx:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            add:
              type:
                headers: false
```

MessageConsumer.java

```
@Service
public class MessageConsumer{

        @KafkaListener(topics = TopicQueueConstant.TOPIC_NAME, groupId = "json",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
   public void listenAsObject(ConsumerRecord<String, Name> cr,
                           @Payload Name payload) {
    logger.info("Logger 1 [JSON] received key {}: Type [{}] | Payload: {} | Record: {}", cr.key(),
            typeIdHeader(cr.headers()), payload, cr);
   }

   private static String typeIdHeader(Headers headers) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(headers.spliterator(), false)
                .filter(header -> header.key().equals("__TypeId__"))
                .findFirst().map(header -> new String(header.value())).orElse("N/A");
   }
}
```

MessageProducer.java

```
@Service
public class MessageProducer{

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessageToTopic(String message) {
       logger.info("sendMessageToTopic service invoked");
       logger.info("sending to topic queue");
       Name name = new Name();
       name.setFname("test");
       name.setLname("test");
       name.setMname("test");
       name.setId(1L);
       //       Message<Name> msg = MessageBuilder
       //               .withPayload(name)
       //               .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, TopicQueueConstant.TOPIC_NAME)
       //               .build();
       this.kafkaTemplate.send(TopicQueueConstant.TOPIC_NAME, "1", name);
       logger.info("message has been sent successfully to topic queue");
   }
}
```

Name.java (POJO)

```
public class Name implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5172012720819652286L;

private long id;

private String fname;

private String lname;

private String mname;

public Name() {}

public Name(@JsonProperty("id") final long id, 
        @JsonProperty("fname") final String fname, 
        @JsonProperty("lname") final String lname, 
        @JsonProperty("mname") final String mname) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.mname = mname;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}

public String getMname() {
    return mname;
}

public void setMname(String mname) {
    this.mname = mname;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name::toString() -> {"
            + "id=" + this.id
            + ",fname=" + this.fname
            + ",mname=" + this.mname
            + ",lname=" + this.lname + "}";
}

}
```

and this is the method in my controller

```
@Autowired
private MessageProducer producer;

@PostMapping(value = "/publish")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> publishMessage(@RequestParam String message){
    logger.info("publishMessage endpoint invoked");
    logger.info("parameter received = {}", message);
    this.producer.sendMessageToTopic(message);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

I am stuck with this problem for almost 2 days now.

Comment: Why are you sending around `Object` instead of concrete types?

Comment: Note: `typeIdHeader` isn't doing what you want because your message has no headers... Maybe try adding unit tests if you are really stuck

Comment: I would try using `@Payload` and `@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY)` in the listener, instead of `@Payload` with `ConsumerRecord<String, Name>`... So, something like: `public void listenAsObject(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key, @Payload Name payload)`

Comment: Add it as an answer. Would make more sense.

Comment: @cricket_007 I wanted it to accept and send any class

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got it working, the reason for the error is because the topic has a queued message that is not in JSON format hence the error encountered. I flushed it out and started my application again then it worked.. In this code set, you need to make sure that the consumer receives a JSON format else you will encounter the infinite error stated in my question above.. Thanks for all the comments and answers!

Comment: This is a bad solution. You are vulnerable to poison pills in your topic.

Answer (score 1):

Tru to configure `JsonDeserializer` on the ConsumerFactory with an appropriate default type to deserialize, instead of configurating it in `application.yml`

Steps on how to configure `JsonDeserializer` in code: [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#serdes)

Comment: we want to avoid config using codes and choose to do all in the application.yml. Though you are correct all tutorials and other blogs do it by manually creating config in the codes..